# Why isn't my function functioning?

Tags: javascript, canvas

I'm painfully amateur so forgive me in advance.
Using canvas I have an image which you can zoom into and then start to draw.
1.  Load image
2.  Select square from grid
3.  Zoom in and switch of zoom and select square
4.  Start to draw
In the drawing function there is a dragging device borrowed from elsewhere on the internet which engages on mousedown and desengages on mouseup.  For some reason this isn't working and my path is continuous.  Can you help?  I'm wondering if it has anything to do with my event listeners which will only work with the window object and not the canvas.  Here's the code:

```
function doFirst(){
var x=document.getElementById('canvas');
context=x.getContext('2d');
pic = new Image ();
pic.src = "kingtut.jpg";
pic.addEventListener ("load", function()
{context.drawImage(pic, 0, 0,1200, 600);},false);
}

var dragging = false;
var radius = 10;

var engage = function (){
dragging = true;
putPoint(e);
}

var disengage = function(){
dragging = false;
}

function square (e) {
xPos = Math.floor(e.clientX/200)*200;
yPos = Math.floor(e.clientY/100)*100;
context.drawImage(pic, 0, 0,1200, 600);
context.strokeRect (xPos, yPos, 200, 100);
}


function putPoint(e){
if (dragging){
context.lineTo(e.clientX, e.clientY);
context.stroke();
context.beginPath();
context.arc(e.clientX, e.clientY, radius, 0, Math.PI*2);
context.fill();
context.beginPath();
context.moveTo(e.clientX, e.clientY);
}
}

function zoom (e) {
var scale = 6;
xPos = Math.floor(e.clientX/200)*200;
yPos = Math.floor(e.clientY/100)*100;
window.removeEventListener("mousemove", square);
context.drawImage(pic, -xPos*scale, -yPos*scale,1200*scale,600*scale);
window.removeEventListener("mousedown", zoom);
window.addEventListener("mousedown", engage);
window.addEventListener("mouseup", disengage);
window.addEventListener("mousemove", putPoint);
}


window.addEventListener("load", doFirst, false);
window.addEventListener("mousedown", zoom, false);
window.addEventListener("mousemove", square, false);
```

Huge thanks!
Nick

Comment: "Why isn't my function functioning?" great!!!

Comment: By saying `path is continuous` you mean it drow a line?

Comment: Yes - the disengage should stop the continuous line between mouse clicks but the line continues.   How does the -1 point work?  Have I asked a bad question?  Could I have found the answer elsewhere?  Sorry to be a pain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Works fine for me. Just removed line, and fixed `putPoint` in `engage`

```
function putPoint(e){
if (dragging){
context.arc(e.clientX, e.clientY, radius, 0, Math.PI*2);
context.fill();
context.beginPath();
context.moveTo(e.clientX, e.clientY);
}
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Biesas/0jkygej5/2/)

**UPDATE:**

There was a  problem with line start position.

```
function putPoint(e){
if (dragging){
context.moveTo(newX, newY); 
context.lineTo(e.clientX, e.clientY);
context.stroke();
context.beginPath();
context.arc(e.clientX, e.clientY, radius, 0, Math.PI*2);
context.fill();
context.beginPath();  
newX = e.clientX;
newY =  e.clientY;
}
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Biesas/0jkygej5/3/)

Comment: Sorry - I haven't made myself clear.  There should be a continuous line as you hold the mousedown which stops when you put the mouse up and then doesn't join to your next mousedown event.  But the line joins up so my disengage function isn't changing dragging.

Comment: Now I see, added UPDATE. Hope it helps.

Comment: Brilliant! So we store the new starting co-ordinates each time we engage and then as the dragging continues we store the latest e.location to continue the line?  Thank you.

Comment: Have accepted answer but it won't let me add points until I have 15 reputations.  Thanks very much for your help.